# Asp.Net Core on Mac OS X connect to SQL Server Linux Docker

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have completed set the sql server linux on docker.

```
microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   5 days ago          Up 18 minutes                 0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                                                                      sql.server
```

When I'm using SQL Operations Studio to connect to the server I able to connect it:

```
Server: localhost
Username: sa
Password: *********
```

but when I'm changing my default connection string on asp.net core default connection

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=PandaMarket.Identity;User ID=sa;Password=*********"
```

I encounter this error message, when performing database update
`dotnet ef database update` from the terminal.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

Comment: Can you please add your `docker run` command or `compose` file (if you used that to run the container). Also, it's not clear from the question what are you running inside what container. I assume you're running two containers, one with `ASP.Net core` and one with `SQL Server`. Is that right?

Comment: Instead of `SQL ID=sa` you need to use `User Id=sa`. Also, try implicitly use `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed basically I have run sql.server in the docker, I would like to perform "dotnet ef database update" It not able to perform it. I didn't use the docker-compose, since still under development.

Comment: Failed to find server. You cannot use localhost since the SqlServer is not on the localhost. You need to use the IP exposed by the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You need to connect to database in your application.json

I do it like this

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=vchasno;User ID=sa;Password=Dontoretto23;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```